# boost::bind encapsulating a HANDLE returned by a COM interface

Tags: c++, com, boost, handle, shared-ptr

I have a Visual Studio 2008 c++ project that uses a COM object like this:

```
ISomeComInterface* foo;
HANDLE file = foo->CreateFile();
// file operations...
foo->CloseHandle( file );
```

I would like to use `boost::shared_ptr<>` to encapsulate the lifetime management of the returned `HANDLE` object. e.g:

```
ISomeComInterface* foo;
boost::shared_ptr< void > file( foo->CreateFile(),
    boost::bind( &ISomeComInterface::CloseHandle, foo, _1 ) );
// file operations...
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile:

```
1>Compiling...
1>Audit Tool.cpp
1>boost\bind\bind.hpp(69) : error C2825: 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>        boost\bind\bind_template.hpp(15) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_bi::result_traits<R,F>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            R=boost::_bi::unspecified,
1>            F=int (__stdcall ISomeComInterface::* )(HANDLE)
1>        ]
1>        Myapp.hpp(78) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            R=boost::_bi::unspecified,
1>            F=BOOL (__stdcall ISomeComInterface::* )(HANDLE),
1>            L=boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<ISomeComInterface *>,boost::arg<1>>
1>        ]
1>boost\bind\bind.hpp(69) : error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>boost\bind\bind.hpp(69) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'
1>boost\bind\bind.hpp(69) : error C2208: 'boost::_bi::type' : no members defined using this type
1>boost\bind\bind.hpp(69) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

What can I do to get the functionality I'm looking for?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: Did you define `BOOST_MEM_FN_ENABLE_STDCALL`? (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html#Q_com)

Comment: @Eric Malenfant - That fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eric answered the question

`#define BOOST_MEM_FN_ENABLE_STDCALL`

htttp://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html#Q_com